# qiskit plots not showing up in spyder console

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder, qiskit

**System Informations**

```
Qiskit version: 0.17.0
Python version: 3.7.7
Operating system: Windows 10 home x64
```

**What is the current behavior?**

I am using spyder 4.1.1 on Anaconda and any time I try to plot data it does not show up. The code runs with no errors but the plot it self does not appear anywhere.

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

Running the code listed below which is from the IBMQ website:

```
import numpy 
import qiskit as qc 
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer
import matplotlib
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_city

circ = qc.QuantumCircuit(3)

circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)
print(circ.draw())
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(circ, backend)
result = job.result()
outputstate = result.get_statevector(circ, decimals=3)
print(outputstate)
plot_state_city(outputstate)
```

**What is the expected behavior?**

for the plot state city plot to show up in the console or somewhere else

**Suggested solutions**

I tried using both matplotlib.pylot.show() and matplotlib.pyplot.draw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follow the instructions under "Spyder plots in separate windows" [here](https://geo-python.github.io/2017/lessons/L7/matplotlib.html#spyder-plots-in-separate-windows). Then you can also call `circ.draw(output='mpl')` to draw the circuit in a window. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I generally use  pycharm ide for running the qiskit code. I think, spyder should also work the same.
Please modify your code as below. I hope, it will work for you.

```
import numpy 
import qiskit as qc 
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer
import matplotlib
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_city
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

circ = qc.QuantumCircuit(3)

circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)
circ.draw(output='mpl')

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(circ, backend)
result = job.result()
outputstate = result.get_statevector(circ, decimals=3)
print(outputstate)
plot_state_city(outputstate)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To print your circuit, you have to type print(name of the circuit) so in your case type print(circ).

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the plots don't show in `spyder` by default. If you run this code in a Jupyter Notebook the plots should show up just fine!

Comment: I understand this, I do prefer spyder over Jupyter. is there anyway to make it work on spyder? if not that is fine but i thought i should ask.

Comment: I have never used spyder before I am afraid so I can't help any further. If when normally using matplot the plots just show up, but here they don't, then I think that may be an issue with qiskit. You can raise it as an issue here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues

Answer (score 0):

1st: I changed the preferences of spyder: Tools ==> Preferences ==> ipython console ==> Graphics ==> Graphics backend ==> Automatic.

2nd: then I have tried the option mentioned in the answer above, with minor modification is that by writing 'mpl' only between the brackets after the word "draw" to have the code be `circ.draw('mpl')`, and things worked fine.